# Почему так происходит, и как это исправить?

Tags: discord.py

Мне в консоли пишет

```
File "bot.py", line 136
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#f00')
                                              ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Но вроде в коде всё нормально, и я не могу понять почему недостаёт пробелов, и где?

```
@bot.command(aliases = ["card"])
async def card_user(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)

    img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#f00')
    
    url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)[:-10]

    r = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    r = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
    r = r.convert("RGBA")
    r = r.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    img.paste(r, (15, 15, 115, 115))

    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    name = ctx.author.name
    tag = ctx.author.discriminator

    headline = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", size = 20)
    undertxt = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", size = 12)

    idraw.text((145, 15), f"{name}#{tag}", font = headline)
    idraw.text((145, 50), f'ID: {ctx.author.id}', font = undertxt)

    img.save("user_card.png")

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File(fp = "user_card.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#f00')
```

Удали перед ним все пробелы, аж до `await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)` что бы было `img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#f00')await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)`
а потом поставь TAB перед `img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#f00')`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Продолжай в том же духе)